# Alguien me podria ayudar a implemetar este este problema en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices, jupyter, matriz

crear una funcion que permita identificar si en una matriz de 5x5 existe 4 valores que se repiten en una misma fila y de una manera secuencial (full).
Por ejemplo

1 2 5 7 11

6 3 3 3 3

12 13 10 8 1

8 9 11 12 1

en esta matriz en la fila 1 se repite 4 veces el numero 3 desde la columna 1 hasta la 4. La funcion no debe permitir la repeticion de valores, en caso de que si se repitan decir Si caso contrario retornar un no

```
matr = []
c = int
d = []
filas = int(input("Cantidad de filas"))
columnas = int(input("Cantidad de columnas"))
for i in range(filas):
    matr.append([0]*columnas)
    
for j in range(filas):
    for k in range(columnas):
        matr[j][k] = int(input("ingrese elemeto en la posicion: %d, %d :" %(j,k)))
        d.append (matr[j][k])
print (d)

for j in range(filas):
    for k in range(columnas):
        if (matr[j][k]==matr[j][k]):
            c=1
        else:
            c=0
if c==1:
    print("SI existe un FULL")
elif c==0:
    print("NO existe un FULL")
```

Como podria leer unicamente las filas

Comment: Preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.

Comment: ¿El código que adjuntas es lo que intentaste? Específicamente, ¿Cuál es el problema o duda?

Comment: Mismo problema que https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376440/python-crear-funcion-en-matrices

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Trata de hacerlo con bucles `for` anidados. Tendrías que hacer otra variable donde iras almacenando un valor para que valides si ya existe ese valor en la fila que estas recorriendo.

Otra opción seria usar un contador de números, y el condicional `if` seria algo como

```
if count > 1:
   print ("Ya se encuentra el valor en esta fila ")
```

Hice algo parecido en Java hace un tiempo.

Comment: Bastante vaga la respuesta. Deberías publicar el código que implementa tu idea y mostrar que funciona.

Comment: Simplemente no hay que responder preguntas mal planteadas, sean buenas respuestas o no.

Comment: No es una observación al que respondió la pregunta si no a *Bastante vaga la respuesta. Deberías publicar el código que implementa tu idea y mostrar que funciona.*. Me refiero a que no importa que tan buena sea la respuesta, si la pregunta no está bien planteada no se debe de responder. Con respecto a  *yo por ejemplo veo mal publicada una que acabas de responder de JS*, sé a cual te refiera y gracias por avisarme voy a tomar nota a corregir la actitud.