# Python crear funcion en matrices

Tags: python, funciones, matriz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Crear una función que permita identificar si en una matriz de 5x5 existe 4 valores que se repiten en una misma fila y de una manera secuencial (FULL). Por ejemplo, en la siguiente matriz en la fila 1, el número 3 se repite 4 veces, desde la columna 1 hasta la columna 4. La función debe permitir como entrada la matriz, y como salida se debe indicar si existe o no un FULL. Retornar "SI" en el caso de existir, caso contrario retornar "NO". Se debe documentar la función.

Comment: Es la misma pregunta que (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376426/alguien-me-podria-ayudar-a-implemetar-este-este-problema-en-python).

Comment: Pero no hay respuesta

Comment: @JordanRomero eso no significa que tenga que formular otra igual.

Comment: pero alguien puede ayudar entonces?

Comment: Amigo @gcoronel99 podrias ayudarme es un codigo como el que menciona el otro compañero pero necesito para hoy, es urgente

Comment: A menos que tengas una duda puntual o problema en **específico**, no puedo responder a la pregunta. ¿Que te impide hacerlo por ti mismo?

Comment: @gcoronel99 falta de conocimiento me impide realizar el código en Python, aun no estoy nivel avanzado

Answer (score 0):

Eso parece una asignación que debes de realizar. Además, seguro que tiene que adscribirse a ciertas restricciones de conceptos (es decir, utilizando numpy eso se resuelve a dos líneas).

Pero lo que tiene que hacer es leer cada linea de esta lista que son a su vez listas y contar cuantas veces aparece cada numero según un conjunto de posibles respuestas (y realmente allí esto lo complicado). ¿Pero como lo harías manualmente? Es el mismo procedimiento:

Empieza con una lista que tenga una secuencia de 9 ceros:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Luego, cuenta en cada fila cuantos 1's hay (puede utilizar el método count) y lo guardas en el elemento de índice 0. Luego cuentas cuantos 2's hay y o guardas en el elemento de índice1, y así sucesivamente. Al final, tendrás algo así como:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1]
```

O sea, hay un 1, tres 6 y un 9. De allí puedes saber si un valor se ha repetido 4 veces para que tu función imprima FULL.

Comment: Pero los valores deben repetirse **secuencialmente**, o sea, estar todos juntos. Entonces, basta con preguntar si las sublistas de cuatro elementos en posiciòn 0 y 1 tiene cuatro valores iguates. Se puede resolver en una linea con Python standard (sin numpy).